# Will an Ajax only website eat memory over time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating an ajax only website so I could use fancy page transition's and other lovely stuff. For all elements I have a piece of JavaScript/jQuery like this:

```
var slider = {
   init: function(){
      if($(".slider").length > 0){
         //do slider stuff
      }
   }
}
```

And at every page load I initialize everything and when that element is at that current page it will do it thing.

```
pageloaded = function(){
   slider.init();
   tabs.init();
   comments.init();
   reviews.init();
   //...
}
```

But my question is. When an old page is removed and it had all kinds of javascript attached to its buttons and other elements. Will the memory and other resources it consumes automaticly be 'freed' when that page is .removed() ?

Are there any other downsides of this way of programming?

Answer (score 0):

This has more to do with performance then memory.

It depends on what you're doing and how you're doing it.

If you're replacing full page loads with AJAX requests (i.e. only doing AJAX calls when a user clicks on a button of link and would have a full page load) then AJAX will decrease server load because you're (presumably) doing less processing and returning less data.

if you're adding auto-update type AJAX and you are polling the server every few seconds then that could increase load depending on the use.

You can have good results assuming you are performing a good implementation.

**EDIT (for your second comment):**

Why I say that you have good results assuming you rely on a good implementation.

Normally the browser keeps an inaccessible, internal reference to the XHR (also called garbage collection root).

This keeps not only the XHR alive for the duration of the request, but also the closure that it references.

After the response comes in, it’s also keeping the response data alive as well. The browser will decide when to free these objects. While older versions of IE seams to keep these references much longer than necessary, modern bwosers have better performace and capabilities.

This is a really complicated issue to explain it in a few words.

So to re-cap:

**You can have good results assuming you are performing a good implementation.**

Comment: No, I mean the first thing you describe. Only do things when a user clicks on a link. However I dont mean the performance back-end but the performance front-end, in the browser. 
Will all the bindings of javascript be cleaned up by the browser when they are removed?

Comment: You sad: `Will the memory and other resources it consumes ` thats why I gave you such an answer. I have made an edit just to respond to your second comment. I hope this will help. You can read all over on the web about this concern. :)

Answer (score 0):

In theory the answer is it won't if everything is done right. :)

When I say done right I mean in 2 places, firstly sometimes there are bugs in the actually browser that can cause memory leaks. Microsoft used to do reference counted garbage collector at one point, and that was a classic example of were the browser vendor made a mistake.  I think all browsers now use a mark and sweep garbage collector.

The other place were you can then get memory leaks, is obviously in javascript, either by you, or third party library's.

Just because Javascript uses a Garbage Collector, still doesn't mean you can't get memory leaks, as some people may suggest.  It is still possible, most common mistake for javascript is with say Event delegation & SetInterval, but you could as easy build up some data on global window object etc.

The main thing to consider is, if my objects are not longer referenced, then yes, all memory for said objects will get freed automatically by the Garbage Collector.

Chrome has some pretty descent debugging tools to examine things like this too.  So if you are concerned your getting memory leaks, have a look there.